# Highcharts x-axis label

Tags: highcharts

In chart, the x-axis labels are overlapping, when chart data is big.
I have used "step" property as follows :

```
xAxis: {                
            labels:{
                step: (stepVal ? stepVal : 0),
                },
    }
```

I calculate the value of stepVal, depending upon data.
This resolves the issue of overlapping labels on x-axis.
But, when I zoom the chart, I want to see all the labels on x-axis.
How to get it?

Comment: Have you specific example of your chart ?

Answer (score 2):

In Highcharts 3.0 you can use

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
    labels: {
        step: newValue
    }
}
```

for updating step. Just setting new value in options for new chart won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this..

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection

You would need to change the xAxis labels steps in the event of a zoom action.  You will need to determine how many labels you would want to show, based on how many labels are visible as a result of the zoom.

Comment: I tried the same but no result found, is there any alternatives. please suggest.